# cy.readfile() fails to read the file from dynamic path

Tags: cypress

I am trying to read a file that is downloaded in the `cypress/downloads` folder. I am preparing the path to the file like this

```
let filename = 'Publisher_' + new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-US').replaceAll('/', '_').toString() + '.html';
let filepath = 'cypress/downloads/' + filename.toString();
cy.readfile(filepath)
```

But `cy.readFile` is giving the below error

```
AssertionError
Timed out retrying after 4000ms: 
cy.readFile("cypress/downloads/Publisher_5_25_2023.html") failed because the file 
does not exist at the following path:

/Users/myMacbook/Desktop/cy-automation/cypress/downloads/Publisher_5_25_2023.htmlLearn more
View stack trace


Print to console
at Context.eval (http://localhost:8080/__cypress/tests?p=cypress/integration/features/publisherMenu/publisher-diary-publisher.feature:13508:23)
at Registry.runStepDefininition (http://localhost:8080/__cypress/tests?p=cypress/integration/features/publisherMenu/publisher-diary-publisher.feature:9254:48)
at Object.fn (http://localhost:8080/__cypress/tests?p=cypress/integration/features/publisherMenu/publisher-diary-publisher.feature:10155:41)
at runStepWithLogGroup (http://localhost:8080/__cypress/tests?p=cypress/integration/features/publisherMenu/publisher-diary-publisher.feature:9859:36)
at Context.eval (http://localhost:8080/__cypress/tests?p=cypress/integration/features/publisherMenu/publisher-diary-publisher.feature:10152:60)
```

However when I do

`cy.readFile('cypress/downloads/Publisher_5_25_2023.html');` then it works perfectly fine

Why it is failing for concatenation? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Very strange! Can you try some debugging steps?

For me, dynamic filenames seem to work fine.

Try this:

```
const filename = 'Publisher_' + new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-US').replaceAll('/', '_').toString() + '.html';
const filepath = 'cypress/downloads/' + filename;

const manualString = "cypress/downloads/Publisher_5_25_2023.html"

console.log("Equality: ", filepath === manualString)
```

(Obviously you will need to update the manualString to today's date.)

There is no need to `.toString()` a thing that is already a string, but that is certainly not going to cause a problem.

I wondered about time zones, but that cannot be the explanation because your error message explicitly states the path it was looking for.

On my system they are exactly equal.

[image]

Having your test code `console.log` the dynamic string, and then separately the manual string, and the test of equality, might also help your debugging.